# on which parameters depend requestAnimationFrame? -- slowness

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, d3.js, requestanimationframe

because of my amount of data, I try to display them in few times, by smallest amount, thanks to requestAnimationFrame.
I'm new with this method and have some issue with it.

It works well for small database, with less than 1000 entries, that is smooth. But when I try it with bigger databases, the loop isn't smooth anymore.
I don't understand this slowness because normally render does the same thing, regardless of the size of "data".

```
function paths(data, ctx, count) {
    var n = data.length,
        i = 0,
        reset = false;
var lastRun=0;
var fps;
function render() {
  var max = d3.min([i+60, n]);
  data.slice(i,max).forEach(function(d) {
      d3.select(".foreground")
              .append("path")
              .attr("d", function(p){ return path(d);
             })
              .attr("stroke", "steelblue");
  });
    i = max;
console.log("end render");
};

(function animloop(){
console.log("animloop");
  if (i >= n || count < brush_count) return;
    lastRun = new Date().getTime();
    requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
    render();
  })();
};


// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) {
   return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}
```

I tried to see where the slowness comes from, thanks to console.log(), but actually the lapse is after render. On the console are printed blocks of "end render - animloop" / a lapse / "end render - animloop". I don't understand this lapse...

When I try to use the debugger step by step, I can't see any difference between the cases "few data" and "big data".

If someone sees a problem in my code or knows the origin of the problem, I'll be very grateful.

PS: speedness now : 50fps for 500 entries, 15fps for 7,000, 5fps for 20,000 (I don't need 60fps but 5 is really not enough).

Comment: Do you mean `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `requestAnimFrame`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edit the question

Comment: requestAnimationFrame requests the next animation frame from the browser, but this occurs after your processing takes place, of course, so if you have a lot of calculations or memory allocation going on, then it's going to slow up to do that before it can get an animation frame for display. You're going to have to look at caching your data, or redesigning what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need your animation’s frame rate to be equal to display’s frame rate (or cannot provide acceptable performance), then consider skipping some frames (to prevent performing time-consuming computations at each frame) based on the time passed to the [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)’s callback in the [`DOMHighResTimeStamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) format.